# WCF Data Services, filtering $metadata requests

Tags: authentication, metadata, wcf-data-services

I'm looking for a clean way to differentiate `$metadata` requests from entity requests with WCF Data Services (*5.5.0*).

Rather than apply authentication at the at the HTTP module level (*as a registered `IHttpModule`*) it seems I would have to apply it later in the request life-cycle.

Unfortunately, the only "later"-time that it seems I can apply it (*and not have it interfere with `$metadata` requests*) is in `QueryInterceptor` methods. The problem here is, there is a number of them, and it just seems silly that I'd have to duplicate even a method call across all of them to authenticate requests.

My question boils down to: at what point in the WCF Data Services request life-cycle should I perform authentication and not have it interfere with `$metadata` requests; *or*, how should I test if a request is for `$metadata` so I can promote the authentication logic back to a higher method.

It seems to me like there would (*read: should*) be an `IsMetadataRequest` property floating around, thus allowing:

```
protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args) {
    base.OnStartProcessingRequest(args);
    if (IsMetadataRequest) {
        return;
    }
    // proceed with auth
}
```

I can hack something out into a service base class that simply reads the URI, but it seems like there should be something more defined.